# How can I ignore a jQuery animation for some time?

Tags: jquery, animation

**Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/XnnvD/4/

That is using a delay to delay the animation for a bit but the problem occurs when the user hovers with the mouse a few times over the black image, the animation will remember to continue.

This is an interesting effect but not what I want. I would like the animation not to occur if the user hovers over a few times, let's say in a second or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to delay the animation until the speed of the mouse implies an intent to hover, look into the [jQuery HoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html).  This plugin can be used to fire a hover callback if and only if the mouse has decelerated enough over an item to imply a hover.  It can be used by including it and replacing `.hover()` calls with `.hoverIntent()` ones.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using the [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function of jQuery.

It can assist in preventing the "queue up" of animations. That seems to be the problem.

The first parameter of stop is to clear the queue.

```
$("#someDiv").hover(function(){
    $(this).stop(true, false).up);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop(true, false).down);
});
```

More examples are at *[Full Cycle of Animation on Hover/Off](http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/)*.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `.stop()` before animation to prevent animation queue buildup.

[prevent-animation-queue-buildup](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup)

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('ul.anim_queue_example1 a')
              .hover(function() {
                  $(this).animate({ left: 20 }, 'fast');
              }, function() {
                  $(this).animate({ left: 0 }, 'fast');
              });
      });
```

Here is the updated JavaScript that fixes the animation queue buildup by using the .stop() method.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('ul.anim_queue_example2 a')
          .hover(function() {
              $(this).stop().animate({ left: 20 }, 'fast');
          }, function() {
              $(this).stop().animate({ left: 0 }, 'fast');
          });
  });
```